Word document overview : bug in table of contents and problems with Word online
Sometimes in some documents, there is a bug using the links inside the table of contents :
first click is ok, document scrolls and then it is possible co come back to the table of contents...
and then no more click is possible in the table of contents
I tried to update the table of contents in Word, ans saving again the document, same problem.
More over, viewing the document is different between :
overview
word online with read only access rights
word online with collaborate access rights
Any clue? :-)
